# How do I put back all my calendars?

Tags: calendar

I accidentally clicked on "Display only this calendar". How do I put back all my calendars? The show all/none doesn't work!

Comment: Software or website you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Google Calendar, simply click on the name of each calendar you want to display.

A bit of a pain, I know.